# create a bat file that executes a php script in while (1) loop

Tags: php, batch-file, windows-10

i want to create a bat file with while(1) loop and execute it with windows task schedule. It should be something like this:

```
While (1)

D:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\php.exe -f D:\wamp64\www\nmedica\index.php external python
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried it? Does it work? Are you getting errors? What is your issue? Btw, won't `While (1)` make it an infinite loop?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - It would... if batch had `while` loops.

Comment: `for /L %%i in () do D:\wamp64\...`

Comment: @SomethingDark Ah. Haven't made a bat-file in over 20 years. :-) Then my "thoughts" would be that the OP should google for a tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it like this with cmd

@echo off

:begin

D:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\php.exe -f D:\wamp64\www\nmedica\index.php external python

goto begin